# 100 fowls problem example in the book.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-diophantine-equations

If a cock is worth 5 coins, a hen 3 coins, and three chicks together 1 coin, how many
cocks, hens, and chicks, totaling 100, can be bought for 100 coins?
In terms of equations, the problem would be written (if x equals the number of cocks,
y the number of hens, z the number of chicks):

$5x + 3y + z/3
 = 100$

$x + y + z = 100$

Eliminating one of the unknowns, we are left with a linear Diophantine equation
in the two other unknowns. Specifically, because the quantity $z = 100 − x − y$, we
have $5x + 3y + \frac13(100 − x − y) = 100$, or

$7x + 4y = 100$
The example in the book states that the general solution is:  $x = 4t, y = 25 − 7t$  so that $z = 75 + 3t$ with t as any integer.

I want to understand how did the author derive above equation to $x = 4t, y = 25 − 7t$ and $z = 75 + 3t$
because from my calculation $x$ becomes $ -100+4t$ and $y = 200-7t$

Comment: $7x + 4y = 100$. move $y$ to the other side and factor $4$ out $7x = 4(25 - y)$. Now we see that $x$ should be divisible by $4$, thus you can write $x = 4t$ for some $t \geq 0$. Dividing by $4$ you get $7t = 25 - y$.

Comment: @guest would u explain how u concider 7x = 4(25-y) as x divisible by 4?  Its 7x not just x that looks divisible by 4 i guess?

Comment: yes, you are right -- $7x$ is divisible by $4$. But $7$ itself is not divisible by $4$, thus the only option left $x$ divisible by $4$. Due to the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic any natural number is uniquely decomposed into the product of prime numbers. This means, if I plug valid $x$ and $y$ into the equation, the LHS shoud decompose the same way as RHS. LHS = $7 \times$ prime numbers inside $x$ and since $7$ is prime then $4$ should "live" inside $x$.

Comment: @guest This makes me even more confusing. I am self studying and The book teaches us solving diophantine equation with simple method that gives answer as x= 4t -100 but the answer u gave is the right one but requires more thought processing than what is in the book. I mean if u had not shown this way i would never thought it the way u telling me. I'm still thinking there should be more simpler way.

Comment: @guest also the answer u gave makes the t different values for x and y. Whereas the t in elephantine equation is requires to be as the same value to satisfy the equation. I know ur answer js right. I just want to understand the concept.

Comment: it doesn't make it different. We start with $7x=4(25-y)$. At this point we understand that $x=4t$. Now we have two equations $7x=4(25-y)$ and $x=4t$ and just plug $x$ in. Or it may be simpler to think this way. You know $4t=x$ (equality relation is symmetric), then multiply both sides by $7$ to get $28t=7x$ and now combine with the initial equation $28t=7x=4(25-y)$. It should be obvious that $t$ is the same for both $x$ and $y$.